# Wilken's Reach and Zunimassas

Tags: diablo-iii

[Wilkens Reach](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/wilkens-reach) is an item that gives Grasp of the Dead no cooldown.

If I use Wilken's Reach with the [Zuni's 6 piece bonus,](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-marrow) and the rune that removes it's mana cost, does it still count as though I am using a mana spender?

Comment: [Spines of Seething Hatred](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/spines-of-seething-hatred) changes Chakram to generate hatred instead of using it, while retaining the bonuses of being a hatred spender. I'd imagine this interaction would work out the same way.

Comment: is the website old? it says it removes the cooldown not the mana cost

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/grasp-of-the-dead He is talking about the Unbreakable Grasp rune you can add to skills.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer So sorry, I forgot to add the rune part to the question. Lyrion is correct with his comment.

Comment: @ChaseC thanks guys, stuff on d3 site is often outdated so appreciate the pointers, IMO it would still count as a spender because of the name of the move, I don't have any official evidence or statements but from how i understand the d3 engine works is if a move is a mana spender by default it remains so even if it has augments that change how it works, augments look in the engine for move name, not it's mechanics, it's the original behavior of the spell/move in question that dictates how it is effected by other augments even when some augments work together to form synergies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested it out in game and can confirm that grasp of the dead still counts as a mana spender even with the unbreakable grasp rune.

Comment: I'll believe you ;)